# A clarification on the command syntax in Kubernetes manifest files

Tags: shell, kubernetes

I'm working on a question that wants me to deploy a pod with the `nginx` image. The pod should sleep for 5000 seconds.

The command can be specified like so:

```
command: ["sleep", "5000"]
```

or like so:

```
command:
  - sleep
  - "5000"
```

Why can't the command be specified like so:

```
command:
  - sh
  - -c
  - sleep "5000"
```

or like so:

```
command:
  - sleep "5000"
```

In other words, I'm confused about two things:

1. What does `sh -c` do? I understand that `-c` is there to denote arguments, but isn't the `sleep` command run using `sh`?
2. When can the command and args be listed on the same line, and when do they have to be on separate lines? In this example, why doesn't `sleep "5000"` work? Why do `sleep` and `"5000"` have to be on separate lines? Also, why are quotes around the number 5000 required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `command` and `args` as in K8s object definitions or manifest are in-facet `entrypoint` and `cmd` fields as found in container image definitions. These are supposed to behave in a certain specific way. for eg: if you look at at how docker images are defined, you would find `entrypoint` and `cmd` as 2 highly used fields.

supplying `command` and/or `args` in K8s object definition overrides `entrypoint` and `cmd` fields of the associated container.

`entrypoint` in docker image definitions for example is allowed either as a single string (`sleep 5000`) or as a broken down array (["sleep", "500"]). either ways, it's eventually broken down into an array of arguments (i.e. `sleep 5000` becomes ["sleep", "5000"]).

**I suppose K8s tries to simplify this by letting you supply this only as an array**.

this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/demystifying-entrypoint-cmd-docker/) is a good reference to understand how `entrypoint` and `cmd` work in combination on container image definitions. The behavior feels a bit unnecessarily complicated and I cannot thank K8s contributors more for they simplified it to some extent at least.

Answer (score 0):

The two ways of running the command:

```
command: ["sleep", "5000"]
```

Is exactly the same as:

```
command:
 - sleep
 - 5000
```

In both cases, it is interpreted as a list. It's two ways of expressing a list.

The command cannot be specified as `command: sleep "5000"` because this would be interpreted as a single argument `"sleep 5000"` rather than as two separate arguments `sleep` and `5000`.

Think of it as running this command in shell:

```
`"sleep 5000"`
```

This would be run as a single command and the `5000` would not be interpreted as an argument. Whereas the expression: `command: [sleep, 5000]` would be interpreted as:

```
`"sleep"` 5000
# or simply... (same as)
`sleep` "5000"
```

Thus being interpreted correctly as an argument of sleep.

For `sh -c`, `sh` calls the program `sh` (shell) as the interpreter and the `-c` flag means to execute the following command as interpreted by this program. `-c` is the flag that tells the shell to execute the command that follows it. So in this scenario, it would be redundant to use `sh -c`, and I'm uncertain if that would even execute correctly.